# Retrofit request without body

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am using the retrofit. But I don't understand how to send a request without a body and I can't find anything about this in the internet... Please, write an example of the request without the body (with an url and header only)

Answer (score 2):

Everything is explained in details in the [retrofit docs](https://square.github.io/retrofit/).

In the very first example you have `GET` call without any body - just to fetch a list of github repos.

```
public interface GitHubService {
  @GET("users/{user}/repos")
  Call<List<Repo>> listRepos(@Path("user") String user);
}
```

Comment: How change thid parameters? (Repo and user)

Comment: Everything depends on the API. Here you need to have a `user` in a path, so you use `@Path` annotation. If there is a different call, let's say to list all users, you would have something like this:

`public interface GitHubService {
  @GET("users/list")
  Call<List<User>> listUsers();
}`
and this is pretty much it.

Answer (score 0):

Just for understanding:

For GET method use:

```
public interface GitHubService {
   @GET("users/{user}/repos")
   Call<List<Repo>> listRepos(@Path("user") String user);
}
```

For POST method use:

```
public interface GitHubService {
   @POST("users/user/repos")
   Call<List<Repo>> listRepos(@Field("user") String user, ......<your_parametres>);
}
```

If you still have any doubt, please comment.